# How to get main page from any part of Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way of getting main page object from any of its child controls? As a possible solution I see here bubbling through parents and stopping as soon as a parent is of PhoneApplicationPage type. It is fine for me, but what if I need to do that from other pages?
I.e. How to get main page of an application from everywhere within the application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your App.xaml, there is a public property called RootFrame it is of type [PhoneApplicationFrame class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe(VS.92).aspx).  It is the container for [PhoneApplicationPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage(VS.92).aspx) as [discussed in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402536(VS.92).aspx).

You can always get to the RootFrame since it's at application scope.  So, for example ...

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
var startPage = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

The page that your app starts on is in `WMAppManifest.xml` ...

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
</Tasks>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to encapsulate the behavior of a pivot item inside a view class. Apparently, SelectionChanged rotates through every pivot item during startup, so I had to do the following:

```
var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;

if (null == frame) //during app load
{
   container = App.Current.RootVisual as MainPage;
}
else //during pivot event;
{
   container = frame.Content as MainPage;
}
```

Container is defined as private MainPage container = null;
Weird.